# Pass Component as prop to 3rd party Component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

While using the OSS "[vuejs-paginate](https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate)" component, I came across the following scenario: We need to pass a component as a property - we have no access to the Paginate component itself of course.

I assume we need to pre-render the component, get the HTML and pass it as a string to the "prev-text" property.

I tried accessing the outerHTML property which could be our solution but no idea where to render the component. (using SFCs)

```js
Vue.component('paginate', VuejsPaginate)

Vue.component('Icon', {
  template: ` <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <
    path
  d = "M19.5 8.07422L12.3533 15.2202C12.2597 15.314 12.1326 15.3667 12 15.3667C11.8674 15.3667 11.7403 15.314 11.6467 15.2202L4.5 8.07422"
  stroke = "currentColor"
  stroke - width = "1.25"
  stroke - linecap = "round"
  stroke - linejoin = "round" /
  >
  <
  /svg>`
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Trying to pass a component in the prev-text prop (it accepts HTML)'
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-paginate@latest"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <paginate :page-count="20" :prev-text="`<icon />`" :next-text="'Next'" :container-class="'className'" />
</div>
```

Comment: copy the code to local, its only a few lines https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate/blob/master/src/components/Paginate.vue tweak it then you can do `:prev-text="icon"` and use component in the component or `<component :is="prevText"/>` etc,

Comment: why not register the component globally that's accessible through the entire project?

Comment: @AFarmanbar how would that solve the issue?
we dont want to bring over to our codebase the plugin

Comment: It's the problem with this third-party component that doesn't accept slots for custom layout. The most straightforward way is to not use Icon component and just provide ready to use html as a prop. Otherwise you'll need to use Vue build with enabled compiler, it doesn't look like a good reason for that

Comment: The Paginate component accepts HTML in the `prevText` prop - you can simply provide the SVG code as a string to it, don't wrap it in a component.

Comment: @IVOGELOV well obviously I dont want to duplicate the component in raw html as that would possibly create maintenance issues down the line .. but if there's no other solution

Comment: Well, if you don't want to provide the component template to the prop (because the prop accepts only plain text or HTML - but not Objects) - then you will have to replicate this Paginate component inside your project and modify its source code to use slots instead of props and then you can put your SVG component inside the relevant slot.